# I2C problem - can't talk to I2C Sensor

Tags: python, i2c, sensor

I have a gas sensor connected to my Raspberry Pi 2 (5V, GND, SDA, SCL) I use the Raspbian OS. I try to communicate with the sensor according to this manual:

http://co2meters.com/Documentation/AppNotes/AN142-RaspberryPi-K_series.pdf

i2cdetect delivers the following the right address : 0x68

I used the following test program: ( http://www.byvac.com/downloads/sws/notsmb_1_0.zip )

GNU nano 2.2.6               File: test.py

```
from notsmb import notSMB
bus = notSMB(I2CBUS)
resp = bus.i2c(0x68,[0x22,0x00,0x08,0x2A],4)
print(resp)
```

But I get write errors all the time:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
resp = bus.i2c(0x68,[0x22,0x00,0x08,0x2A],4)
```

EDIT to add:

The complete code I have used:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
from notsmb import notSMB
I2CBUS = 1
CO2ADDR = 0x68
READ = 0x22
readBytes = [0x00,0x08,0x2A]
bus = notSMB(1)
while True:
   try:
      pi=bus.i2c(CO2ADDR,[0x22,0x00,0x08,0x2A],4)
      time.sleep(0.1)
      co2Val=(pi[1]*256+pi[2])
      print(co2Val);
      f=open("/var/www/bhm/K-30/co2wert.txt","w")
      f.write(str(co2Val))
      f.close
      break
   except:
      blank=0;
```

And the error message:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo python /var/www/bhm/K-30/co2messung.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/www/bhm/K-30/co2messung.py", line 12, in <module>
pi=bus.i2c(CO2ADDR,[0x22,0x00,0x08,0x2A],4)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: Could you post the script you are actually using?  That snippet is incomplete.  By the way the problem is fairly obvious, the code you are using would confirm the problem.

Comment: sorry, i used the code from: http://co2meters.com/Documentation/AppNotes/AN142-RaspberryPi-K_series.pdf

Comment: If you want help please post the code you are using.

Comment: Looking at some [notSMB](http://www.pichips.co.uk/index.php/RPi_Not_smBUS) information, I see another tool recommended to use for i2c communication, [Linux_i2c](http://www.pichips.co.uk/index.php/I2C), could give that a try? Would need to change your code, but not too much.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't have the CO sensor to test, but...

From the `notsmbmodule.c` file it looks like you have to call `bus.open(1)` before using the `.i2c(...)` function.

When you create the instance of `bus` the file descriptor (fd) and address (addr) are both set to -1

```
static PyObject *notSMB_new(PyTypeObject *type, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    notSMB *self;
    if ((self = (notSMB *)type->tp_alloc(type, 0)) == NULL)
        return NULL;

    self->fd = -1;
    self->addr = -1;

    return (PyObject *)self;
}
```

When you call `bus.i2c(...)` it is trying to do an `ioctl(...)` on the file descriptor without having done an `open(...)` to get a valid file descriptor first.

So, I **think** it may work if you change your code like so (add the `bus.open(1)` line):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
from notsmb import notSMB
I2CBUS = 1
CO2ADDR = 0x68
READ = 0x22
readBytes = [0x00,0x08,0x2A]
bus = notSMB(1)

bus.open(1)

while True:
   try:
      pi=bus.i2c(CO2ADDR,[0x22,0x00,0x08,0x2A],4)
      time.sleep(0.1)
      co2Val=(pi[1]*256+pi[2])
      print(co2Val);
      f=open("/var/www/bhm/K-30/co2wert.txt","w")
      f.write(str(co2Val))
      f.close
      break
   except:
      blank=0;
```